# Update columns from a CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have the following code which is supposed to update each row in my Rental model with the attributes from each row of the CSV file. The row with an ID of 1 in the database should have its attributes updated with the values of line 1 in the CSV etc... I have 10000 rows in table and 10000(excluding header) in CSV.

However instead of updating the attributes in the model where id = row it is updating all row attributes in table with the first row of CSV, then the second etc...

Any help would be appreciated!

```
csv_text = File.read(Rails.root.join('db', 'Lpostcodes.csv'))
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  postcode = row['postcode']
  latitude = row['latitude']
  longitude = row['longitude']
  puts $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER
  #update a particular row
  Rental.update($INPUT_LINE_NUMBER, postcode: postcode, latitude: latitude,
           longitude: longitude)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't actually explain why you're seeing what you're seeing, I would have thought the *actual* results you'd have seen would be that just one row in your DB was updated over and over with each line in the CSV.

I'm also very surprised that with that `puts $INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` in your loop that you haven't seen what I would expect (a single number printed over and over again).

This is because `$INPUT_LINE_NUMBER` is not set automatically in every `each` in Rails, it's not even set by a `File.read`, so in your code it will be whatever it happened to be at the end of the last `IO` loop.

The simplest way around this is to use the loop index as your id instead of trying to use the line number, so instead of `csv.each` use `csv.each_with_index`:

```
csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
  postcode = row['postcode']
  latitude = row['latitude']
  longitude = row['longitude']

  Rental.update(i, postcode: postcode, latitude: latitude,
           longitude: longitude)
end
```